# Not able to use CfnJson

Tags: go, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use CfnJson to get a value from a token.

```
    foo := awscdk.NewCfnJson(stack, aws.String("test"), &awscdk.CfnJsonProps{
        Value: cluster.ClusterOpenIdConnectIssuer(),
    })
```

But when I try to use it with a awsiam.NewRole I get following error:

```
panic: "Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: \"${Token[TOKEN.372]}:sub\" is used as the key in a map so must resolve to a string, but it resolves to: {\"Fn::Join\":[\"\",[{\"Fn::GetAtt\":[\"EKSCluster676AE7D7\",\"OpenIdConnectIssuer\"]},\":sub\"]]}. Consider using \"CfnJson\" to delay resolution to deployment-time.\nObject creation stack:\n  at stack traces disabled.."
```

---

```
test := map[string]interface{}{"StringEquals": map[string]interface{
foo.Value().ToString(): "system:serviceaccount:default:external-dns"}}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: See  https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5352 and especially eladb's use example...

Comment: Thanks. But the example is for TypeScript, I would like to see an Golang example.